# Ag grid with Angular2

Tags: angular2-forms, ag-grid

According to my application i have some issues Regarding to the AG Grid implementation.
how to perform CRUD operations using Ag grid that Ag grid should contain select/richSelect, Date Fields, Checkboxes inside columns.
I am displaying Existing Records From DataBase Table and i am providing new records(empty records) at last of Grid to insert new records.
I am able to display text in columns but i am unable to show the values of 
Dates, select/richSelect, checkbox of existing records in database table.
In This new empty records some columns contain checkboxes, select/richSelect, Date vales.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying checkbox and binding it to data (True/False), try this code while defining columnDefs.

```
 columnDefs: [               
            {
                headerName: 'Admin', 
                field: 'isAdmin',
                cellRenderer: (params) => {
                    if (params.value) {
                        return `<input type="checkbox" checked  />`;
                    }
                    else {
                        return `<input type="checkbox"  />`;
                    }
                }
            }                
        ]
```